# Save Pdf as a Fdf/x using VBA and Java

Tags: javascript, ms-access, adobe

We are trying to convert existing pdf files to pdf/x to meet a customer requirement.

I'm using the following code to save a pdf file as a pdf/x file. The JSO.SaveAs causes the following error: **"UnsupportedValueError: Value is Unsupported Parameter cConvId"**
Is there a better way to do this?

```vb
Sub SaveAsPDFX()
    Dim AcroApp As Acrobat.CAcroApp
    Dim PDDoc As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
    Dim JSO As Object
    Dim SavePath As String
    Dim Filename As String
    
    Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
    Set PDDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    
    'Open PDF file
        PDDoc.Open ("c:\test.Pdf")
        Set JSO = PDDoc.GetJSObject
        
        'Save as PDF/X-1a
        JSO.SaveAs "c:\testx.Pdf", "com.adobe.acrobat.pdfx", True
        
        'Close PDF file
        PDDoc.Close
        
    
    Set JSO = Nothing
    Set PDDoc = Nothing
    Set AcroApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The error basically tells you all you need to know, `"com.adobe.acrobat.pdfx"` is not a valid `cConvId`.

Use the right `cConvId`:

```vb
JSO.SaveAs "c:\testx.Pdf", "com.callas.preflight.pdfx", True
```

These can be found in [the docs](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/library/jsapiref/doc.html#saveas)